# The border line doesn't extend to the whole page ? CSS

Tags: html, css, border

This is my CSS code.
but for some reason the border length is only going half of the page 
and i want it to be extended till the end of the page.

```
section.courses {
  float: left;
  width: 760px;
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
```

THANK YOU

Comment: Because of this `margin-left: 30%;`

Comment: margins are **outside of borders**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your border-right to extend to the end of the page (ie bottom of the page), the height of section.courses should be equal to full height of the page. You can try assigning this code

```
section.courses
{
    float:left;
    width:760px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    margin-left: 30%;
height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: It won't work, I don't understand what the problem I think something is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding

height:100vh

And the container would extend, extending the border as well